# How to discover data products created using Insomnia workspace offered by Platform of Trust?

Tags: api, platform, platform-of-trust

I have created a small identity network using Insomnia workspace as it described here https://developer.oftrust.net/guides/workflow-using-insomnia-workspace/ I have account on sandbox.

I wanted to validate the identity graph was created as defined so I tried some requests from Identity API. As described in [docs here](https://docs.oftrust.net/#identities-v1-discovery). Tried https://api-sandbox.oftrust.net/identities/v1/discovery with query parameters values:

```
fromId : <building_identity_id>
linkContext: https://standards.oftrust.net/v2/Context/Link/BelongsTo/
identityContext: https://standards.oftrust.net/v2/Context/Identity/Equipment/Device/
linkDirection : IN
maxDepth : 5
offset: 0
limit : 100
```

and got in response identities object with some identities.

Then I tried https://api-sandbox.oftrust.net/identities/v1/dataDiscovery with query parameters values:

```
fromId : <building_identity_id>
linkContext: https://standards.oftrust.net/v2/Context/Link/BelongsTo/
identityContext: https://standards.oftrust.net/v2/Context/Identity/Equipment/Device/Sensor/TemperatureSensor/
linkDirection : IN
maxDepth : 5
offset: 0
limit : 100
```

and got response with "dataProducts": {}

**What is wrong in above **https://api-sandbox.oftrust.net/identities/v1/dataDiscovery** request?**

I see https://standards.oftrust.net/v2/Context/Identity/Equipment/Device/Sensor/TemperatureSensor/ is defined and it was used as context in Insomnia workspace setup of identity network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use another query parameter, basically which discovers the **AtDataProduct** type of Link ( which has been created between Sensors and Data products)

```
atDataProductContext : https://standards-ontotest.oftrust.net/v2/Context/Link/AtDataProduct/
```

See this note [from guide](https://developer.oftrust.net/guides/identities-and-links/#exploring-identities-inlinks-and-outlinks):

A special link type is AtDataProduct. In an identity network, a sensor identity MUST be connected to a Data Product with a link type AtDataProduct. The direction MUST BE "from sensor to Data Product". This is important to consume harmonized data flow in an identity network.

In a nutshell, part of the identity network should be something similar to this:

**Temperature Data Product <--AtDataProduct-- Temperature Sensor --BelongsTo--> Room**